# What are the benefits of using `and` instead of `&&` when defining concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, naming-conventions, concept

I found that some CppCon speakers used `and` instead of `&&` to define concepts and used `&&` in "normal" boolean expressions, but I can't figure out the benefits of doing so.

The only material about naming convensions of concepts that I can found is [P1851: Guidelines For snake_case Concept Naming](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1851r0.html), but it says nothing about this.

Can anyone tell me why?

Example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept boolean_testable
    = std::convertible_to<T, bool>
      and requires(T&& t) {
            { !std::forward<T>(t) } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
          };
```

Instead of:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept boolean_testable
    = std::convertible_to<T, bool>
      && requires(T&& t) {
           { !std::forward<T>(t) } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
         };
```

Although the complete substitutability between `&&` and `and` caught my eye, I still can't figure out why some programmers deliberately choose to use `and` **only when** defining concepts. I noticed they still used `&&` in other context (boolean expressions, `T&&`...). I can't figure out the benefits they got from such style.

I'm not asking for the difference between `and` and `&&` but the motivation of using `and` instead of `&&` **only when** in concept definition. There's no duplicate question as far as I know.

Answer (score 9):

There is absolutely no difference between `&&` and `and`. As tokens they behave identically in all aspects except that the preprocessor `#` stringify operator respects their different spelling.

For example you can even replace `T&&` with `T and` and the code will still have identical meaning.

This is purely a style choice.

See [[lex.digraph]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex.digraph).

Comment: really? Is this guaranteed or just an artifact of `T&&` being introduced only in C++11? I thought its only about the operator.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No, they are equivalent on the level of preprocessor tokens. I also fixed a minor mistake in my answer. The same goes for `T&` vs. `T bitand`.

Comment: @FeignClaims can you point to the relevant section in the standard ? I didnt bother to look. I only checked compilers and they do agree

Comment: @FeignClaims [`int and x = 42;`](https://godbolt.org/z/xbrzhdx9r) weird but compiles

Comment: @user17732522 My bad, wrong typo used when i try.

Comment: I learned something new today:  `T and` and `T bitand`.  Two somethings actually!  Along similar lines, my team at work has taken to doing `if (not ptr) ...` rather than `if (!ptr) ...` because we find it more legible.

Answer (score -1):

In summary, the benefits might be:

- `and` is an English word. Using `and` (along with `or` and `not`) makes the concept definition read like a beutiful verse.
- In concept definition it's pretty common to have a lot of rvalue-reference, so using `and` instead of `&&` helps readablity.